# Do arithmetic schemes have non-singular alterations?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, resolution-of-singularities

Let $X$ be an integral normal flat finite type scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$.

> > Does there exist a proper surjective generically finite morphism of schemes $Y\to X$ with $Y$ an integral regular finite type scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$?

I could not find such a result in the literature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Theorem 8.2 in de Jong's original paper [dJ].

[dJ]  de Jong, A. J., [*Smoothness, semi-stability and alterations*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02698644). Publ. Math., Inst. Hautes Étud. Sci. 83, 51-93 (1996). [ZBL0916.14005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0916.14005).

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I didn't see this (I of course looked at de Jong's original paper, but not carefully enough it seems).